# How to sequence conditions when using either

Tags: haskell, either

So I'm building this CLI todos app to learn some Haskell and I am trying to streamline error handling (I feel that there's too much code using my current approach).

And so I've written this function to update a task at a specific position by applying a function over it:

```hs
  updateTodoAt :: Int -> (Todo -> Either Error Todo) -> [Todo] -> Either Error [Todo]
  updateTodoAt position fn todos
                  | n < 0 = Left "Must be a strict positive, bruh!"
                  | n >= length todos = Left "Out of bounds?"
                  | otherwise = fn (todos!!n)
                                >>= (\todo -> Right(take n todos ++ [todo] ++ drop (n+1) todos))
```

This works fine, however I feel that I'm missing something and there should be a way to write this using some `*>` or `>>` or `>>=`, but I can't seem to be able find the combination. I've just started grasping how to chain these together... :)
The reasoning for trying to accomplish this is because this function is being called within another that does it's own pre-validations and the code already is messy.

I've tried various permutations in the lines of the next block (it's just an example), but from the first moment I felt this approach can't work because this isn't the way to "cast" from Maybe to Either.

```hs
  updateTodoAt position fn todos = fuu n < 0 "Must be a strict positive, bruh!"
                    *> fuu (n >= length todos) "Out of bounds?"
                    *> fn (todos!!n)
                    >>= (\todo -> Right(take n todos ++ [todo] ++ drop (n+1) todos)) 
                  where n = position - 1

  fuu :: Bool -> Error -> Maybe Error
  fuu True e = Just e
  fuu False _ = Nothing
```

My intuition tells me that there should be a function that can be chained like this.

Fyi: `type Error = Text`, I'm using Protolude and OverloadedStrings

The code is up at https://github.com/ssipos90/todos-hs but it's a bit 'dated. I've started working on parsing the "database" file using megaparsec, but I think error handling is more important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of `fuu` that you're looking for is:

```
fuu :: Bool -> Error -> Either Error ()
fuu True e = Left e
fuu False _ = Right ()
```

Here's why...  The operator `(*>)` has type:

```
(*>) :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f b
```

In this context, `f` is specialized to `Either Error`, so it's actually:

```
(*>) :: Either Error a -> Either Error b -> Either Error b
```

If you want to write `fuu p "xxx" *> other_action`, the type of the result will be the type of `other_action` (namely, `Either Error b` for some `b`).  You need to define `fuu` so that the supplied `fuu p "xxx"` has type `Either Error a` for some type `a`, where it doesn't matter what type `a` is:

```
fuu :: Bool -> Error -> Either Error ???
fuu True err = Left err
fuu False _ = Right ???
```

If you find yourself in a situation where you need to supply a `???` where the value and the type don't matter, the value/type `()` is always a good bet:

```
fuu :: Bool -> Error -> Either Error ()
fuu True err = Left err
fuu False _ = Right ()
```

Note that it's common to write:

```
when (n < 0) (Left "Must be a strict positive, bruh!")
```

using `when` from `Control.Monad`, instead of bothering to define `fuu`.

Also, you may find your function looks a little more natural when rewritten in do-notation:

```
import Control.Monad

updateTodoAt' :: Int -> (Todo -> Either Error Todo) 
     -> [Todo] -> Either Error [Todo]
updateTodoAt' position fn todos = do
  when (n < 0) $ Left "Must be a strict positive, bruh!"
  when (n > length todos) $ Left "Out of bounds?"
  todo <- fn (todos !! n)
  return $ take n todos ++ [todo] ++ drop (n+1) todos
  where n = position - 1
```

Comment: Cool. I've tried writing `fuu` as `fuu :: Bool -> Error -> Either Error a` but it errored.
Also I've searched hoogle for `Bool -> e -> Either e a`. Never crossed my mind to use the "empty tuple". Thanks a lot!

Comment: `fail s` is not `Left s`, though.

Comment: `fail` is for handling pattern-match failures; it's not meant to signal an arbitrary error.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `fmap` here:

```
updateTodoAt :: Int -> (Todo -> Either Error Todo) -> [Todo] -> Either Error [Todo]
updateTodoAt n fn todos
  | n < 0 = Left "Must be a strict positive, bruh!"
  | n >= length todos = Left "Out of bounds?"
  | otherwise = let (l, (todo:r)) = splitAt n todos
        in fmap (\todo -> l ++ [todo] ++ r) (fn todo)
```

Comment: Code works fine, I was just trying to rewrite it without using a guard.At this point, I have a lot of helper functions or case statements because of how I've written it. I'm trying to understand how to chain and nest `Either`s.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `!!`. There are really only two error conditions:

1. `n` is negative
2. The input list is empty (which implies the non-negative `n` is too large)

Given a non-negative `n` and an non-empty list, you'll either apply the function to the first list element, or recurse.

```
updateTodoAt n _ xs
    | n < 0 = Left "negative index"
    | null xs = Left "index too large"
updateTodoAt 0 fn (x:xs) = (: xs) <$> (fn x)
updateTodoAt n fn (x:xs) = (x :) <$> updateTodoAt (n-1) fn xs
```